# Parsing data containing '.' from a text file in R

Tags: r

I was trying to parse all the rows with the missing data '.'  as I need the missing data information. I used the following code and got the following error messages. I was able to make this code work with a simpler data file with 4 columns where the second and third columns were the ones with A,T,G,C and '.' in the cells. However, this same code is not working with this dataset. It could be due to difference in data structure as only 2 variables show up when i use the ncol function. A small snippet of how the output should look is given below the snippet of the data file.

```
> test2.txt <- read.table("ref_qry.snps", header=F, sep="\t", skip=5)

> subset(test2.txt, rowSums(test2.txt[1:2] == ".") >0) 

[1] V1 V2
    <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> subset(test2.txt, rowSums(test2.txt[,1] == ".") >0)
    Error in rowSums(test2.txt[, 1] == ".") : 
      'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions


1341   C T   9464894   |        8      373  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1360   C .   9464875   |        1      392  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1361   A .   9464875   |        1      392  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1362   G .   9464875   |        1      392  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1363   A T   9464875   |        1      392  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1402   . A   9464835   |        5      432  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1407   A G   9464830   |        4      437  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1


1360   C .   9464875   |        1      392  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1361   A .   9464875   |        1      392  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1362   G .   9464875   |        1      392  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
1402   . A   9464835   |        5      432  |  9798893  9465266  |  1 -1  Supercontig_12.1  scaffold_1
```

Comment: What's the issue? Do you wan the dot to be coded as a missing value? Use `na.strings = (".")`, as documented in `?read.table`.

Comment: This question would be much clearer if you showed your desired result. Or described it in words. Or even both!

Comment: I was trying to parse only '.' from the file shown in the data above. I was able to parse this data from another file which had only the first four columns which was a tab delimited created in excel with the above code. However, when I use the same code I get the following error message: <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names).  When I try to see the structure of the file, it gives me 2 variables in the columns as opposed to what I see in the data file.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your expected result. It would also be helpful to show a few lines of the raw file. I don't think you're using "parse" correctly. When you say "parse only '.' from the file" it sound like you want to read the `.` characters and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you Gregor! I just edited my question and I am looking for the entire row with all the columns which has the missing data as '.' instead of A,T,G,C. A small snippet of the desired output file has been included. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this achieve what you want:

```
# set any type and any amount of "white space" as separator
x <- read.table("ref_qry.snps", header=F, sep="", skip=5)
#                                         ^^^^^^
# now we have distinct columns that we can check for "."
x[ x[2] == "." | x[3] == ".", ]
```

It works for me  just copying and pasting your data into a text file.

Comment: Thanks @vaettchen. When I tried the code it gave me the following error message: Error in `[.data.frame`(x, 3) : undefined columns selected

Comment: We probably need your file in original format, otherwise it will only be guesswork.

Comment: Thank you @vaettchen. The problem got resolved. The previous code worked fine once I removed the sep "\t" argument. So, the problem was the file was not being read in properly in r. I just noticed that you had changed the argument: sep "\t" to sep = " " . My mistake. The problem would have been solved long ago if I had noticed the change in the read.table code. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I should have pointed out in my answer - will edit accordingly. Would be nice if you accept the solution.

Comment: I accepted the answer now. Didn't know of that possibility. I was trying to vote earlier. Thank you.